# Unable to connect to server database from java desktop application

Tags: java

I created a java desktop application. I am trying to connect this application to mysql
server database. But it is throwing socket exception. I tried in all the ways to solve this issue
but none of them worked for me. The problem which I got is mentioned in this link http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-849637.html

[image]

Please help me in this regard.
Will be really thankful..

Comment: does the java app run on the same box as the database? mysql database has to be configured to accept connections from remote machine. Refer to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/3686310/176569

Comment: hi thanks for the response..i gave telnet ipaddress portnumber in cmd prompt and checked but it displayed the message "could not open connection to the host, on port 3306: connect failed"

Comment: can you connect from the same system with the mysql client? The one that ships with mysql?

Answer (score 0):

According to your respnose on Oct 3'12 at 10:27, you already found out this is not Java related.

Fix your network problem:

- ensure MySQL is really running
- ensure you use correct IP/port
- ensure no firewall is blocking traffic