# Not able to connect MYSQL Server Using SAS ACCESS TO MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sas

I am not able to connect to MYSQL server using SAS access to MYSQL.

Code:

```
libname mysqllib mysql user=XXXXXX password=XXXXX database=test
server="XXXX.vip.its.XXX.com";
```

Error:

> ERROR: Error trying to establish connection: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'XXXX.vip.its.XXXX.com' (146)
>   ERROR: Error in the LIBNAME statement.

Comment: That sounds like you have an issue with properly identifying the server, or ports or somesuch.  Perhaps you have to specify a noncustom port, or a more precise URL.  I'm going to call this a duplicate, in large part simply to redirect you to a good answer for how to test things.  146 in any event I believe is a generic 'cannot connect' answer in the MySQL world, so I don't think SAS is relevant here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to connect to remote MySQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3686233/unable-to-connect-to-remote-mysql-server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So without a MySQL server to connect to and without knowing your setup, all that anyone can give you is pointers.

First, make sure you can connect to that MySQL server with those parameters.  Use another client and see if that is correct.

Second, make sure that MySQL server is listening on port 3306.  If not, use the PORT= option to change from the default 3306.

Third, try putting your username and password in single quotes(' ').